# Limits and continuity at endpoint(s) of domain

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

> We now give the definition of the limit of a function at a boundary
>   point of its domain. This definition is consistent with limits at
>   boundary points of regions in the plane and in space, as we will see
>   in Chapter 14. When the domain of $ƒ$ is an interval lying to the left
>   of $c$, such as $(a, c]$ or $(a, c)$, then we say that $ƒ$ has a limit
>   at c if it has a left-hand limit at $c$. Similarly, if the domain of
>   $ƒ$ is an interval lying to the right of c, such as $[c, b)$ or $(c,
> > b)$, then we say that $ƒ$ has a limit at $c$ if it has a right-hand
>   limit at $c$.
>
> Consider the function $f(x)=\sqrt{4-x^2}$ with domain $[-2, 2]$. This
>   function has a two-sided limit at each point in $(-2, 2)$. It has a
>   left-hand limit at $x = 2$ and a right-hand limit at $x = -2$. The
>   function does not have a left-hand limit at $x = -2$ or a right-hand
>   limit at $x = 2$. It does not have a two-sided limit at either $-2$ or
>   $2$ because $ƒ$ is not defined on both sides of these points. At the
>   domain boundary points, where the domain is an interval on one side of
>   the point, we have $ \lim_{x \to -2} \sqrt{4-x^2} = 0$ and $ \lim_{x\to 2} \sqrt{4-x^2} = 0$.
>   The function $ƒ$ does have a limit at $x =-2$
>   and at $x = 2$.

This is from my book. There are some things that is still vague to me.

1. Is it true that $ \lim_{x\to 2} f(x) = 0$ and $ \lim_{x \to -2} f(x) = 0$ implicitly means that the left/right limit exists, and not both sides? Does saying $f$ is continuous at $x=-2$ and $x=2$ means that $f$ is implicitly right continuous (for $x=-2$ only) and left continous (for $x=2$ only), and not both?
2. How about if I have a function $a(x)=\sqrt{4-x^2}$ for all $x \in [-2,2]$, $a(x)=0$ for all $x<-2$ or $x>2$. Does it still apply $ \lim_{x \to -2} a(x) = 0$ and $ \lim_{x \to 2} a(x) = 0$, however, now it's implicitly meant from both sides?
3. If $b(x)=\sqrt{4-x^2}$ for all $x \in [-2,2]$, $b(-3)=0$. Is it still true that $ \lim_{x \to -2} b(x) = 0$, I don't think so since the domain is not $[-2,2]$, but please verify. How about the continuity of $b$ at $x=-2$?

[image]

Comment: This text does not address continuity at all, your questions are partly irrelevant.

Comment: @YvesDaoust But the questions do.

Comment: @YvesDaoust The book only gives an explanation about continuity with a question and gives the definition of it (the picture above).

Comment: @Adola: this was missing in the initial version of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the domain, you have

- a *limit* if both the *left-* and *right- limits* exist and are equal;
- at the same time, it is a *two-sided limit*.

At an endpoint,

- a *limit* if the left- or right- limit exists;
- there is no *two-sided limit*.

Comment: Does using Epsilon-deta limits only applies $|x-c|<\epsilon \implies |f(x)-L|<\delta$ with $x$ in the domain of $f$?

Comment: @Adola: it does.

Comment: If the domain is $[-2,2] \cup \{ -3 \}$, what would be considered the endpoints of this domain?

Comment: @Adola: endpoint is not formally defined. Prefer boundary point.

Comment: @Adola: no, $-3,-2$ and $2$.

Comment: I typed limit sqrt(4-n^2) as n->2+ on WolframAlpha, it returns $0$, this means that wolframalpha is wrong?

Comment: @Adola: no Alpha computes in the complex, not in the reals, and as usual is right. You see this on the curves.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, the right limit at $-2$ equals the left limit at $2$ which is $0$. $f$ is continuous at $x=-2,2$ because $f(2)=f(2^-)$ and $f(-2)= f(-2^+)$. Note that we only need to consider what’s in the domain.
2. If you have defined $a(x)$ for every $x\in \mathbb R$, then the domain would be $\mathbb R$ instead of $[-2,2]$. Now, $$a(2)=a(2^-) = a(2^+)=0$$ (similarly for $a(-2)$) and so it is still continuous.
3. Now the domain is $[-2,2] \cup \{-3\}$. Yes, $$\lim_{x\to -2} b(x)= 0= \lim_{x\to -2^+} b(x)$$Again, $b(-2^-)$ is not defined and so we have continuity at $-2$.