# Why the value of the above limit as x tending to 0 is 0?

Tags: limits

[image]

Why the value of the above limit as x tending to 0 is 0? According to me it should be undefined because we can't find the value of the above limit as x tending to 0-. Only we can find the value of the above limit as x tends to 0+. I know that if we find the value using L-Hospital's rule then the limit will be 0, but the fact is that the above function is undefined for 0- I.e. for every negative values of x.

Comment: If I had to guess, Wolfram is using a complex-valued definition for $\log(x)$ on the principal branch for $x<0$. Interpreted as strictly a real-valued function with domain $(0,\infty)$, only the limit $x \to 0^+$ should exist, yes.

Comment: But for a limit to be defined both left hand and right hand limit should exist

Comment: WolframAlpha calculates both the left hand and right hand limit to be zero. 

But also note that in the case of a lefthand boundary point of the domain of a function (such as zero here) you could just define the limit to be the righthand limit (see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3659819/limits-and-continuity-at-endpoints-of-domain)

Comment: The left hand limit will be undefined

Comment: (Only seeing this now but) Yes, you've said that already. And interpreted as a function of reals, you are right. The issue is that there is a larger context than purely real-valued functions, evidently, in which makes sense. You can define limits for complex-valued functions after all... (Alternatively, if you just change the definition of limit to allow you to use $x \to 0$ when, on one side, you don't even have values to input into the function, you get smcc's comment.)

Comment: So the solution here is: (1) change your definition, (2) investigate logarithms and complex numbers, or (3) accept that you're correct in that the limit doesn't exist if we ignore complex numbers.