Wording of a limit question in high school mathematics
I have come across the following question in an AP Calculus example question on limits, and I want to make sure whether the wording of the question is correct.
The answer states that the limit exists at $x=-2$, because the right-hand limit exists. I thought if I were in the exam I may be confused, because the students are taught something like, if the left-hand limit is equal to the right-hand limit then the limit is whatever that limit is. But at $x=4$ only a one-sided limit exists.



Also see, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3659819/limits-and-continuity-at-endpoints-of-domain.

Is this an ACTUAL AP question (former question appearing on an actual test that has since been released) or a sample test-prep question? I ask because this type of issue used to be avoided on actual AP tests since texts and teachers vary on this point (pun intended), and also this (limits at an endpoint of the domain) is not something sufficiently important to waste a question on. (I'm a former AP Calculus grader.)

I think the confusion arises because most HS textbooks don't address limits at end-points. At end-points it's not a $2$-sided limit; at end-points, the left or right limit just needs to exist. When points are in the interior of the domain, then it must be $2$-sided.

If $x_0 \in \text{domain}(f)$ is an end point, then $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0}f(x)$ exist means $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0^+}f(x)$ $\textbf{or}$ $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0^-}f(x)$ exist;
If $x_0 \in \text{domain}(f)$ is not an end point, $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0}f(x)$ exist means $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0^+}f(x)$ $\textbf{and}$ $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0^-}f(x)$ exist, and they are equal.
